# Why doesn't Google's AMP-html allow at least one external CSS file?

Tags: amp-html

It seems to me that having a shared CSS files across multiple pages that can be cached by the browser would be a benefit to the user experience.  There comes a point where 1 additional connection on the first load is worth the savings as the user navigates through your site.

I can't find any information that explains why this isn't the case now or why the AMP team choose such a seemingly extreme rule in this case

Comment: Well, if you want a great explanation about that issue, then only an AMP team engineer can answer your question. But if we based on their official [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages), it is stated that "Like all web pages, AMP pages are styled with CSS, but you can’t reference external stylesheets. Certain styles are disallowed due to **performance implications**; inline style attributes aren't allowed". Also, external style sheets are not permitted to avoid additional request for css.

Answer (score 2):

- External CSS blocks the Rendering until it is load (Look in Firebug the network trace, the loading of other files are stop until the CSS is load). And a external CSS needs time.
- Your are right if a user visit more than one site it is faster in theory. The downloadtime thats add's the css in the html is so low. Try to find the different time. Every additional ext. CSS starts the CSS calculation again.
- And the focus is that a vistor see your site the first time.
- The browser load the CSS from the browser Cache (maybe on the Harddrive) and by include in HTML it is directly there.
- Of course you should't load many css libarys in the Content. Google say's CSS up to 10.000 line's are okay. If you need so much line's think about a CSS optimation.

Comment: I like your point about it boiling down to hard drive versus network.

Your hard drive will be faster than the network almost all of the time.  Especially in developing countries.  I still think this is a flawed strategy from Google.  It pushes sites to be a spoke on the Google hub, which is why I suspect this hasn't changed yet.